# regrouping similar column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with many lines and columns, looking like this :

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 |

I would like to keep only the values that are different from the previous index and replace the others by 0. On the example dataframe, it would be :

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 0 | 2 |

What is a solution that works for any number of row/columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'd like to keep the values where the `diff`erence to previous row is `n`ot `e`qual to 0 (i.e., they're not the same), and put 0 to other places:

```
>>> df.where(df.diff().ne(0), other=0)
       col1  col2
index
1         0     1
2         5     0
3         0     4
4         0     0
5         3     0
6         2     0
7         0     1
8         0     2
```